# Python mock patch a coroutine function within another function using pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio

I have two functions in module_name/app.py

```
async def f1(arg):
    # do something
    return arg + '1'


async def f2(arg):
    result = await f1(arg)
    return result
```

I try to test f2 and mock f1 using pytest and asynctest.
It only works, if I do

```
def sf_f1(arg):
    return 'some value'

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_f2():
    with asynctest.mock.patch('module_name.app.f1', side_effect=sf_f1):
        assert 'some value' == await f2('test')
```

test PASSED

But, I want do to something like this

```
import module_name

@pytest.fixture()
def mock_f1():
    return asynctest.CoroutineMock(module_name.app.f1, side_effect=sf_f1)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_f2_2(mock_f1):
    assert 'some value' == await f2('test')
```

I get

```
   assert 'some value' == await f2('test')
   AssertionError: assert 'some value' == 'test1'
     - some value
     + test1
```

Why doesn't the second way work?

Comment: What isn't working? What are your desired results and what is the actual results?

Comment: Mock isn't work and function f1 runs. When I want to add return value or side_effect to mocked function.

Comment: I add side_effect function. 
In the first case, it works. In the second case function f2 runs, not side_effect function.

Comment: A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help here, a code that shows what you are doing and then explain what you expect to happen instead.  Maybe put print statements in the various functions and state which prints you expect to happen when the mock is used.

Comment: Sorry, for this example. I left some changes in a code and added assertion error. I hope this code is more complete and readable.

Comment: I want to mock using fixture, because i can re-use it while testing other functions, which calls f1(). How can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second example, in `mock_f1` fixture you create a `CoroutineMock` object and return it. But you don't overwrite `module_name.app.f1` function: `Mock`-like objects don't patch anything automatically.

Here is an illustrating addition to your example:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_f2_2(mock_f1):
    print('fixture value:', mock_f1)
    print('actual module_name.app.f1 function:', module_name.app.f1)
    assert 'some value' == await f2('test')
```

Which will print somethink like this

```
fixture value: <CoroutineMock spec='function' id='139756096130688'>
actual module_name.app.f1 function: <function f1 at 0x7f1b7e1139d8>
```

When you call `f2`, it uses `f1` function from the module, which is not overriden.

So here is how this would work for you:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_f1(monkeypatch):
    fake_f1 = asynctest.CoroutineMock(module_name.app.f1, side_effect=sf_f1)
    monkeypatch.setattr(module_name.app, 'f1', fake_f1)
    return fake_f1
```

As you probably know, `monkeypatch` will make sure that changes are applied only while the fixture is active.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works!
I only recently began to use pytest and mock, so you really helped me a lot!